# What is Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-emulator

What kind of mobile applications we can develope in an android sdk? What are the components needed to install it. I have already checked the Android developer's site i m getting so confuse

1. what i have to do to learn it?.
2. What is an Android Emulator?

Comment: I am sorry about being so pedantic, but is this a programming question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What kind of mobile applications we
>   can develope in an android sdk?

Almost all applications you can imagine. Your imagination (and skill) is the limit.

> What i have to do to learn it?

First, it would be good if you already can code in Java. If not, you probably have to start with that, so that you understand the basic principles in Java. Afterwards I would start with doing some simple tutorials, and then you can go on and develop your own applications. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869338/where-to-start-to-learn-android/2869373#2869373) I already listed some good tutorials and other resources which will facilitate your start in Android.

```
What is an Android Emulator?
```

The Android Emulator replicates an typical interface to your desktop machine, so that you don't need a real mobile device while developing your application. You can emulate the behavior of a mobile device on your desktop. However it is important to note that the Emulator has some limitations, like for example Bluetooth is not supported, and it is problematic to simulate touch movements.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I know java but I want to ask is that when we design our application like we do in ASP.Net is there any need to use another tools for design purpose.

Comment: @Mayur Chavan for designing the user interface you don't need any other tools. But there are from builders available (in the SDK and standalone).

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a bit too broad, but I'll give it a shot. The Android SDK lets you develop any kind of mobile application. It also lets you develop other kinds of things like Live Wallpaper ( http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-wallpapers.html ).

1. To learn it you should know the Java programming language, the Android OS and the Android APIs. Much documentation is on the Android site you mentioned, but there are also a lot of books and tutorials available.
2. The emulator provides an environment for you to test your applications. It is similar enough to the real OS to let you test your application, but you should always test on a real device before shipping.

Comment: Is there any problem to install it on windows?

Comment: @Mayur It works on Mac, Windows and Linux, but you need to install the version for the particular platform.